# How to manage big data for iOS app that displays location of all its users

Tags: android, ios, database, performance

I need to develop an iOS (and pref also compilable as Android) app that keeps track of the GPS coordinates of all its users, along with other properties.

Everybody needs to be able to see the the location of every other person on a map and search based on profile characteristics.

I am trying to get an idea of the best architecture of this. Would it be possible to just create a local app that works with a remove sql database? Would that be scalable enough? Or would I need some kind of backend processing?

I know software like PhoneGap can connect the App to a backend website with RESTful API. My question is mainly about what technique to use to handle the live/big data stream. Could mysql handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Having every user be capable of viewing other user's locations will require a centralized backend, ala AWS/Parse(RIP)/Kinvey etc etc.

Comment: Couldn't I create that myself, using a PHP api, or java on google engine?